# Sum users who did not place an order in the previous month group by monnth

Tags: sql

I have 2 table

Table1 > Orders before 2017
Table2 > Orders After 2017

Table1 Like This :

| UserID |
| --- |
| 2324 |
| 2325 |
| 2326 |
| 2329 |
| 2331 |
| .... |
| .... |
| 130.234 |

Table2 Like This :

| YearMonth | UserID |
| --- | --- |
| 2017-1 | 1245 |
| 2017-1 | 2326 |
| 2017-1 | 4672 |
| ..... | .... |
| 2017-2 | 1356 |
| 2017-2 | 1782 |
| ...... | .... |
| 2017-6 | 7834 |
| ...... | .... |
| 2017-12 | 4567 |
| 2017-12 | 8954 |

I want to this table as result

| YearMont | Count(NewUserID) |
| --- | --- |
| 2017-1 | 12.345 |
| 2017-2 | 13.456 |
| 2017-3 | 16.768 |
| 2017-4 | 17.126 |
| 2017-5 | 17.678 |
| 2017-6 | 18.895 |
| 2017-7 | 12.613 |
| 2017-8 | 14.811 |
| 2017-9 | 14.343 |
| 2017-10 | 19.111 |
| 2017-11 | 19.321 |
| 2017-12 | 20.601 |

what I want; Sum users who did not place an order in the previous month  group by monnth

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest two levels of aggregation, first at the user level and then at the first month level.  For the first level of aggregation we can remove users in `table1`:

```
select first_yearmonth, count(*)
from (select t2.userid, min(t2.yearmonth) as first_yearmonth
      from table2 t2
      where not exists (select 1 from table1 t1 where t1.userid = t2.userid)
      group by t2.userid
     ) t2
group by first_yearmonth
order by first_yearmonth;
```

Comment: Thank you for  your answer, it's really perfect!